# If $f(x)$ is continuous on $0$ then $x f(x)$ differentiable on $0$

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$ then $g(x) = x\cdot f(x)$ differentiable at $0$.

On the one hand in my calculus book they prove it like that:

$$g'(0) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{\frac{g(h) - g(0)}{h}} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{\frac{h\cdot f(h) - 0\cdot f(0)}{h}} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{\frac{h\cdot f(h)}{h}} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{f(h)} = f(0)$$

but on the other hand this function exist:
$f(x) = x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$  for any $x \neq  0 $
and $f(x) = 0$ for $x = 0$

It seems to contradict the proof isn't it?

Comment: No. why do you think so?

Comment: to get a contradiction to the claim you need to disprove the differentiability of $x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x})$.

Comment: but $x^2sin\frac{1}{x}$ isn't differentiable at 0

Comment: @avi: That is differentiable at 0.

Comment: ok now i understand my mistake. I should have check differentiability directly from the definition...

Answer (score 1):

The OP may be looking at the formula

$$g'(x)=2x\sin\left({1\over x}\right)-\cos\left({1\over x}\right)$$

which holds when $x\not=0$, and observing that $\lim_{x\to0}g'(x)$ does not exist.  But there's nothing that requires a function to have a limit at a point in order for it to be defined there.