# Prove the function $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto xf(x)$ is differentiable where $f$ is continuous at $0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function which is continuous at $0$. Prove that the function

\begin{equation}
g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto xf(x)
\end{equation}
is differential at $0$.

Is it enough to say:

$g(0) = 0f(0)$
and as $f$ is continuous a $0$, it is also differentiable.

Comment: See also: [If $f(x)$ is continuous on $0$ then $x f(x)$ differentiable on $0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745598/if-fx-is-continuous-on-0-then-x-fx-differentiable-on-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac{g(x)-g(0)}{x} = f(x) \to f(0)$ when $x \to 0$, so the limit exists and equals to $f(0)$ which is the value of $g'(0)$. In other words, you get $g'(0) = f(0)$ and $g$ is differentiable at $x = 0$.